# loading angular2-modal error with rc1

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, angular2-directives

I'm using this library [angular2-modal](https://github.com/shlomiassaf/angular2-modal) that has some different options, like bootstrap and vex for modals in angular2.

Vex seems to work fine, but as soon as I switch to bootstrap, I get the following error:

> responsive-application.js:84712 Uncaught TypeError: core_1.style is not a function

Comment: This is `modal`s library error, not angular

Comment: I think `core_1` comes from here `var core_1 = $__require('@angular/core'); `

Comment: Try to upgrade to Angular 2 rC4

Comment: Thank you for your answer, yes i put there it was a angular2-modal library problem, that the hole name of the library and i never met it was an angular2 problem!

your answer did help me! but instead of uploading my angunlar2 to RC4, that would hald be a lot of trouble with te rest of the project!

what i did was to downgrade the library version to a working version with Angular2.RC1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AS I mention on the respone @AngJobs did help me to find a solution, i do a reverse path and instead of upgranding angular y downgrade de library to a working version with RC1

Hope this experience help other Devs :)